I use sqlalchemy and want to get new values of computed field in returning after updating
Simple sample:
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Computed, update, insert, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, async_sessionmaker, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, declared_attr


engine = create_async_engine(url="postgresql+asyncpg://db_user:db_pass@localhost:54320/db_name")
async_session = async_sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class BaseTable(DeclarativeBase):
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        return cls.__name__.lower()


class Tablichka(BaseTable):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    quantity = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    price = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    total_cost = Column(Integer, Computed("quantity * price"))  # Attention!

I want to update the row using an orm query. I need to get a result, so I use returning:
async def run():
    async with async_session() as session:
        # Inserting
        statement = insert(Tablichka).values(quantity=2, price=100).returning(Tablichka)
        obj = (await session.execute(statement)).scalar_one()
        # total_cost: wait 200, really 200
        print(f"total_cost: wait 200, really {obj.total_cost}")
        id = obj.id

        # Updating
        statement = update(Tablichka).filter_by(id=id).values(quantity=4, price=100).returning(Tablichka)
        obj = (await session.execute(statement)).scalar_one()
        # total_cost: wait 400, really 200
        print(f"total_cost: wait 400, really {obj.total_cost}")   

        # Selecting
        statement = select(Tablichka).filter_by(id=id)
        obj = (await session.execute(statement)).scalar_one()
        # total_cost: wait 400, really 200
        print(f"total_cost: wait 400, really {obj.total_cost}")

        await session.commit()

    async with async_session() as session:
        # Selecting in another session
        statement = select(Tablichka).filter_by(id=id)
        obj = (await session.execute(statement)).scalar_one()
        # total_cost: wait 400, really 400
        print(f"\ntotal_cost: wait 400, really {obj.total_cost}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
    loop.close()

After the update, I expect to get a recalculated total_cost, but I get an old total_cost. I get updated fields except calculated fields. At the same time, the value is recalculated in the database. This confirms the select query in the new session.
I use the following versions:
python = "^3.10"
sqlalchemy = "^2.0.35"
asyncpg = "^0.29.0"
greenlet = "^3.1.0"

How do I solve the problem?

Asked and answered on GitHub here

I started a discussion on this issue in the sqlalchemy github (https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/11911 ). This was caused by a bug. In advance, this should be fixed in sqlalchemy version 2.0.36.

So, after the sqlalchemy developers fixed this bug, this problem no longer occurs if you upgrade sqlalchemy to 2.0.36.
If you have to work with older versions of sqlalchemy, then you can try the following method, which works for me:
async def run_create(session: AsyncSession):
    statement = insert(Tablichka).values(quantity=2, price=100).returning(Tablichka)
    obj = (await session.execute(statement)).scalar_one()
    # total_cost: wait 200, really 200
    print(f"total_cost: wait 200, really {obj.total_cost}")
    return obj.id


async def run_update(session: AsyncSession, id: int):
    statement = update(Tablichka).filter_by(id=id).values(quantity=4, price=100).returning(Tablichka)
    obj = (await session.execute(statement)).scalar_one()
    # total_cost: wait 400, really 400
    print(f"total_cost: wait 400, really {obj.total_cost}")


async def run():
    async with async_session() as session:
        id = await run_create(session)
        await run_update(session, id)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
    loop.close()

